# String literals not working properly in React

Tags: reactjs

Can´t seem to get the string literals around "code" to work (I need to make the inline code in markdown). I tried using "" and single quotes as well, but alas, no dice. Any ideas?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import MarkdownExample from "./previewer";


class Editor extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: `# h1 Heading 
              ## h2 Heading
              Here´s a link too: (http://dev.nodeca.com)
              Inline ``code``

              Indented code

              // Some comments
              line 1 of code
              line 2 of code
              line 3 of code
              Block code "fences"

An image:

![Stormtroopocat](https://octodex.github.com/images/stormtroopocat.jpg "The Stormtroopocat")
> Blockquotes can also be nested...
>> ...by using additional greater-than signs right next to each other...
> > > ...or with spaces between arrows.

Ordered list

1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
2. Consectetur adipiscing elit
3. Integer molestie lorem at massa


## Emphasis

**This is bold text**

__This is bold text__

*This is italic text*

_This is italic text_`
```

};

Comment: To print value in template literals you have to use ${variableValue} but you are again using `` inside template literal which isn’t correct

Comment: How would that work? The problem does seem to lie in the string literals, since it works when I add a different line to it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simple here, and is occurring because you have ``code`` in your markdown.

All you need to do is to escape your backticks within markdown using \ before the backtick symbol.

I have also created an example for you here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dx2v6t?file=index.js

Comment: Thank you,  but that doesn´t seem my problem. I need the backtick in code so that it renders properly as markdown.

Comment: @HernanAriel This is your problem. Backticks are still there. They are escaped to be properly parsed as template literal. Whatever the problem with markdown rendering, it's specific to how you render it, not to this string.

Answer (score 0):

This part

```
 `# h1 Heading 
  ## h2 Heading
  Here´s a link too: (http://dev.nodeca.com)
  Inline ``code``

  Indented code
  ...
```

isn't parsed as intended. Backticks in the middle are parsed as template literal delimiters.

This is considered separate template literal and a [tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_templates):

```
  `# h1 Heading 
  ## h2 Heading
  Here´s a link too: (http://dev.nodeca.com)
  Inline `
```

I.e. it is parsed as:

```
 (`# h1 Heading 
  ## h2 Heading
  Here´s a link too: (http://dev.nodeca.com)
  Inline `)(...)
```

In order for it to be parsed as single template literal, backticks should be escaped:

```
 `# h1 Heading 
  ## h2 Heading
  Here´s a link too: (http://dev.nodeca.com)
  Inline \`\`code\`\`

  Indented code
  ...
```